# Content not giving same result in crome

Tags: html, html-table

I have used the same code which you have explained here and i found out that it only works on "FIREFOX" and does not display the same asked table in "GOOGLE Crome".

```
<table border="1"  align="center" cellpadding="10px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th rowspan="3"> Day</th>
    <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2"> Schedule</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <th>Begin</th>
    <th>End</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td rowspan="2">8.am</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5. pm</td>
            <td>Introduction to XML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          
            <td>Validity:DTD and relay ng</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <!-- set rowspan=4 instead of 3 -->
            <td rowspan="4">Tuesday</td>
            <td>8. am</td>
            <td>11.am</td>
            
            <!-- set rowspan=2 -->
            <td rowspan="2">Xpath</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- made rowspan =2 for below td elements -->
            <td rowspan="2">11. am </td>
            <td rowspan="2"> 2.pm</td> 
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">XSL TRansform</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           
            <td>2 pm</td>
            <td>5 pm</td>
            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    
        <tr>
            <td>Wednesday</td>
            <td>8 am</td>
            <td>12pm</td>
            <td>xsl: formating objects</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

below is the attached link of files containing images of the results in firefox and crome.
[firefox result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXDTm.png)
[crome result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DB1s.png)